# How to get the id off a class into a webservice using Jquery

Tags: jquery, anonymous-function

I have several "edit in Place" text boxes that sit within a generated table and I need to pass an identifier from the page to a webservice, thus...

```
$(document).ready(function () {

 $(".extraText").editInPlace({
            url: "http://" + document.location.host + "/MenuEdit/EditExtra/",
            params: "Id=" + function() {return $(this).attr("rel")},
etc
```

As I have several, of the same boxes I need to call by class and not by Element, but I need to get the Id attribute "rel" off the individual element and pass this through to the web service.    At the last point of the anonymous `function (function() { return $(this).attr("rel")},)` I keep coming unstuck.  I have tried many variations of this and if I put an alert in on some variants and it will give me the correct result, but wont return it. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you have to loop over each element if `editInPlace` does not provide any possibility to to get a value at runtime:

```
(function() {
    var url = "http://" + document.location.host + "/MenuEdit/EditExtra/";
    $(".extraText").each(function() {       
         $(this).editInPlace({
            url: url,
            params: "Id=" + $(this).attr("rel"),
        etc 
        });
    });
}());
```

(the immediate function is just to not pollute the global namespace with the `url` variable and avoiding of repetitive string concatenation)

Not sure what you want to achieve with the anonymous function... as it stands, it just tries to concatenate a function with a string.

Answer (score 2):

Your function is never called. When you write something like:

```
"Abc " + function() { return 'def'; };
```

Javascript will concatenate "Abc " with the evaluation of `function() { return 'def'; }` which is a Function object!
It's equivalent to:

```
var foo = function() { return 'def'; };
"Abc " + foo;
```

Javascript will convert `foo` into a string, and the result will be:

```
"Abc [Object]"
```

because the string representation of a Function object is '[Object]' (or maybe `"Abc function() { return 'def'; }"`, it depends on your JS implementation).

This is slightly different from:

```
"Abc " + foo();
```

which is a function **call** and **executes** the function, and gives the expected result:

```
"Abc def"
```

Follow the recomendation of Felix Kling to find a solution to your problem.

Comment: And just for fun, that can be made to work by making the function self-invoking: `"Id=" + (function() {return $(this).attr("rel")})(String)`

Comment: Unfortunately, in this case `this` = the Global Object, and this is not what is expected. Only the use of `each` to iterate on jQuery elements so that `this` will take all desired values can do the job.

Comment: Good point - I had it in my head that there was iteration involved.

Comment: There isn't an iteration involved, it is just a single Id I need to pass to the webservice.  I previously had it working by element, but it meant having a call from many elements. ie  $(".extraText1").editInPlace({ ....  $(".extraText10").editInPlace({. Surely that would not be the cleanest solution?  The self invoking function above gives 'undefined' at the web service end.  Rgds Mark

Comment: There is an iteration if you don't want to replicate code. The solution given by Felix Kling is the right one. Use it like: `$(".extraText1 .extraText2 .extraText3 ...").each( ... )` or better `$('.allEditInPlaceHaveThisClass').each( ... )` ; And of course the self-invoking function gives `undefined` since `this=window` in this case. You should read some documentation on JS, this is a difficult language.